# Render child page inside the base html template in Python Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to render a template inside the base html page. Base html has the header, footer, menu common for the whole site. The middle section of the page has to come from the child page. I think I have everything right, 200 OK, but it is not working, I don't see the content of the child page, form and div. I only see base.html for all requests.  What am I missing?

```
project
   |
    ---templates/base.html
    ---templates/childpage.html
```

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/custom.css' %}">
</head>

<body>

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

**childpage.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="">

</form>
<br><br><br>

<div class="something">
<a>some content</a>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**views**

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')

def askforchild(request):
    return render(request, 'childpage.html')
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('', views.home, name='Site Home Page'),
    url('askforchild', views.askforchild, name='child page'),
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? Is the base template missing?

Comment: I don't see the content of the child page, form and div. I only see base.html.

Comment: Isn't the problem the missing space at the end of `{% endblock content%}`?

Comment: Fixed and checked. No change. I just see base page, no child page in the middle of the page as expecting.

Comment: I guess that reason of this in base you have to write {%endblock content%} not just endblock

Comment: @BakhtiyarBekbergen Fixed. Still the same result. For any page request, it renders the base page.

Comment: The closing tag is `{% endblock content %}` .There is a space missing in your code. Also your child template seems ot be just empty? What do you expect to see? It renders the base page because well, it is the base page.. So it  probaby renders the base page and an empty child page?

Comment: @Phanti Fixed the spacing, still the same result. The child page has a form and a div. It should be visible when I click on `ipadd:8000/askforchild`, but all I see is base page, header footer menu, and with 200OK

Comment: @KapishM uhm but what is inside the div/form? Did you try to display a plain <p> tag?

Comment: @Phanti form has a lot of html, many inputs for date, time, place details. So there is enough Html to show. Tested with p, a tag. Same result. For ALL requests it just returns one file, base.html. Even if I completely empty the child file to have no reference to base.html, still returns base.html in response. I looked at the request and responses. `GET ipadd:8000/askforchild` 200 ok, and response has all the html of the base, though the child page this time is totally empty. So problem is in routing, not recognizing the views?

Comment: @KapishM for me url pattern and view looks good as well, otherwise you wouldn't get `200` in return. Tough to verify from here, but I guess the issue is somewhere within the template tags

Comment: @PhantiI renamed the child file to something else in views. and still 200 ok, with base html in response.

Comment: renamed the child file on the disk too, still the same response.

Comment: Solved it! It was the url pattern match sequence. I had the `""` home page at the top that was matching all requests. I had to put that the bottom of the url list so others dont miss-hit on it.

Answer (score 1):

The url list for home page `""` had to move to the bottom of the url list. Regex was catching all requests as home page requests. Catch all, an empty pattern should be at the bottom of the url list.